# Facebook API: How to change app action in the sidebar of the canvass page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a canvass app on FB (iframe) and I was wondering how one would change the verb that is displayed on the live stream on the right hand side of the application. I've seen some apps display it like "John is playing APPNAME" and "John played APPNAME".

I've been searching for the api for this on the docs but couldn't find any. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Darn, simply had to set the category to Game. Now I feel kinda stupid :)